# Genesis Block mismatch with seemingly exact same file

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I run a private Eth network with geth. I have two nodes on the network. I had these nodes connected over the last months. However, today when I try to connect one to the other I get an error:

```
err="Genesis block mismatch - 6231b02ac967dff9 (!= d4e56740f876aef8)"
```

When I display the hashes in geth they are also different:

1st machine:

```
> admin.nodeInfo.protocols.eth.genesis
"0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"
```

2nd machine:

```
> admin.nodeInfo.protocols.eth.genesis
"0x6231b02ac967dff9b0c799e956094408959de862d720d08776302ffefba0300b"
```

However, it is the same file (I copied it with scp). Also when I run

```
md5sum CustomGenesis.json
```

it will result in the same hash for both machines. Furthermore I start the nodes with the exact same settings (apart from the directory path).
Might this be related to different geth versions (1.8 on machine 2 and 1.9 on machine 1) or to a recent crash of machine 1?

Comment: It might be that one node wasn't initialized properly.

Comment: do you know how I can test for that? I use the exact same settings as I used the previous months when the machines were still synchronized.

Comment: From geth console execute eth.getBlock(0) should return the same genesis block.

Comment: they show different blocks. The first machine shows the block from the genesis file, the other machine shows a completely different block

Comment: I removed the /chaindata and /lightchaindata folder from the machine with the wrong genesis block. Now it initialized correctly and is synchronizing. Thank you very much for your help!